# Can I use "click and hold" sighting?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

By default, you look down the sights by clicking the right mouse button, and stop looking down them by clicking it again.

Is it possible to change the controls to look down the sights when you press the right mouse button, and stop looking down the sights on mouse release?

Comment: If it's not an option in the options menu, you could probably do this with AutoHotKey, assuming Modern Warfare 3 PC plays nice.  I don't own this version of the game, but perhaps someone who does can take a crack at a script.

Comment: At least with the PC versions, there should be a "Aim Down the Sight" control and a "Toggle" version.  Make sure you bind to the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at you control-settings, there are two options:

- **Hold** Aim Down Sight
- **Toggle** Aim Down Sight

i don't know the exact lables for these options as i only own the german version, but the first one is what you're looking for wile the second one seems to be the one you're using - just change your settings.

Comment: Another click and hold feature is with all snipers, so it is easier to hard scope and get a one shot kill.